# react-datepicker in formik form throwing error when a date selected

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-datepicker

I'm new to react world and trying a basic form using formik. I have been trying fix the below error but unsuccessful.

Below is the form component with formik and react-datepicker. I have another function validate which validate if the user has entered startdate.

```
    import React from "react";
    import { useFormik } from "formik";
    import Datepicker from "react-datepicker";
    import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

    const CreateAuction = () => {
      const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
          startDate: new Date(),
        },
        validate,
        onSubmit: values => {
          const inputValues = JSON.stringify({
            startDate: values.startDate,
          });
        }
      });

      return (
        <>
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="page-header">
              <h2>Create Auction</h2>
            </div>

            <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="startDate">Start Date</label>
                <br/>
                <Datepicker
                  id="startDate"
                  name="startDate"
                  className="form-control"
                  selected={formik.values.startDate}
                  onChange={formik.handleChange}
                  onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                value={formik.values.startDate}
                />
                {formik.touched.startDate && formik.errors.startDate ? (
                  <div className="text-danger">{formik.errors.startDate}</div>
                ) : null}
              </div>

              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                 Create 
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </>
      );
};
```

**When i select the date in date picker its throwing an error.**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/xxx/source/repos/my-appy/src/Formik.tsx:622
  619 |   : (eventOrTextValue as React.ChangeEvent<any>).currentTarget;
  620 | 
  621 | const {
> 622 |   type,
      | ^  623 |   name,
  624 |   id,
  625 |   value,
View compiled
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/xxxx/source/repos/my-app/src/Formik.tsx:664
  661 |     if (isString(eventOrPath)) {
  662 |       return event => executeChange(event, eventOrPath);
  663 |     } else {
> 664 |       executeChange(eventOrPath);
      | ^  665 |     }
  666 |   }
  667 | );
View compiled
onChange
C:/Users/xxxx/source/repos/my-app/src/Formik.tsx:1208
  1205 |   });
  1206 | 
  1207 |   return React.useCallback(
> 1208 |     (...args: any[]) => ref.current.apply(void 0, args),
  1209 |     []
  1210 |   ) as T;
```

Answer (score 0):

first  i think it is `DatePicker` not `Datepicker` 
make sure the `formik.values.startDate` is in  a numeric format like `DD/MM/YYYY` other way `selected={formik.values.startDate}` with throw an error 
and also did you try to use `Field` of Formik ?

Comment: so what's the solution of it? I'm curious since it's using useFormik